# A good place to begin with Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

So I bought the Arduino starter kit a few weeks ago and I've done a few of the projects in the book supplied with the set. Unfortunately the book is quite poor, with inaccurate explanations and sometimes no explanation behind what they want you to do in the projects.

So I'd like to know what people would reccomend? I found 2 well reviewed books; Arduino for Dummies and Arduino Workshop, but I'm torn which to take. So I'm asking in here in hope that I can save time and money on buying and reading a good book from the start.

I'm a programmer by profession and also know a bit of physics, but have little experience with electronics.

Comment: Try to come up with a project you can make that is useful in your life, and just make it. Just like programming; you'll learn the most by just doing, running into problems and finding solutions. Book are overrated.

Comment: I got some ideas of what I'd like to do, but I know already they will be complicated projects, so I'd like to build up some basic knowledge before I begin.

Comment: Try spitting them into sub-problems. E.g. you project requires a lcd display. Try to get an lcd display working. Your project needs to sound a buzzer when some condition is met. You need to read light levels; try getting a LDR or phototransistor to work.

Comment: I'd guess that with your background, you could find some useful tutorials online, from which you could build a couple of projects and learn while you're doing it. Since you have a goal - or at least a direction - in mind, you can direct your searches toward features you think you'll need.

Comment: could you please say *which* starter kit you have? Some of them are very good, some are not so good. The one I have is very clear, all the experiments worked, and the purpose was well understood - it is shown in this video review where I gave it a good rating... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pf4qosqpv3A

Comment: @Jasmine Sorry Jasmine, I hadn't considered that. It's the official starter kit sold on Arduinos own website.

Comment: There is some good discussion going on here but I'm going to have to close this question as it's "primarily opinion based" and there is no correct answer. The arduino chat would be a better place for something like this. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8489/pin-13

Comment: @sachleen Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

I have read a lot of materials, watched many videos and completed lots of searching to find great stater Arduino lessons. By far the best place I found was

opensourcehardwaregroup.com
[Free to start learning Arduino site](http://opensourcehardwaregroup.com)

Free initial course and if you like the lessons you can pay a small fee to get to the advanced course. You will learn a lot!